React 19's new experimental useActionState() and resetting specific structured data within "formData"
I've implemented React 19's new experimental feature useActionState() in my form, which returns structured data.
In the structured data, it contains fields for error/successful messages that will show in the front end when data is present. Typically, these messages can be "closed" in the front-end by setting the (previously state) data to false with onClick().
I've tried formData.success = null, for example, but I had a feeling that wouldn't work (which it didn't).
So, what's the proper way of resetting this data? Note: I want to reset specific fields in the formData not the entire object.
Example of structured data return:
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "No record found to update",
  "formData": {
    //..
  }
}

Form.tsx:
const [formState, formAction, isPending] = useActionState(
  updateSettings,
  initialFormState,
);

<form action={formAction}>
  {formState?.message && (
    <div>
      {formState.message}

      {/* Doesn't work */}
      <button type="button" onClick={() => formState.message = ''}> 
        Close Button
      </button>

    </div>
  )}
</form>

updateSettings.tsx
export async function updateSettings(
  prevState: UpdateSettingsResponse | null,
  formData: FormData,
): Promise<UpdateSettingsResponse> {
  //..
  return {
    success: response?.success || false,
    message: response?.message,
    formData: rawFormData,
  };
}

